# gcomm connection timed out error while setting up mariadb-galera cluster

Tags: installation, mariadb, galera

While installing mariadb/galera I am not able to establish cluster connectivity because of gcomm connection timeout error. 
Also I have seen that gvwstate.dat file is not getting created.

```
May 22 11:00:45 seliius20664.seli.gic.ericsson.se mysqld[28769]: at gcomm/src/gcomm/types.hpp:String():30
May 22 11:00:46 seliius20664.seli.gic.ericsson.se mysqld[28769]: 2019-05-22 11:00:46 0 [Note] WSREP: view((empty))
May 22 11:00:46 seliius20664.seli.gic.ericsson.se mysqld[28769]: 2019-05-22 11:00:46 0 [ERROR] WSREP: failed to open gcomm backend connection: 110: failed to reach primary view: 110 (Connection timed out)
May 22 11:00:46 seliius20664.seli.gic.ericsson.se mysqld[28769]: at gcomm/src/pc.cpp:connect():158
May 22 11:00:46 seliius20664.seli.gic.ericsson.se mysqld[28769]: 2019-05-22 11:00:46 0 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs/src/gcs_core.cpp:gcs_core_open():209: Failed to open backend connection: -110 (Connection timed out)
May 22 11:00:46 seliius20664.seli.gic.ericsson.se mysqld[28769]: 2019-05-22 11:00:46 0 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs/src/gcs.cpp:gcs_open():1458: Failed to open channel 'itinframonitoring_production_test' at 'gcomm://seliius20663,seliius20664,seliius20662': -110 (Connection timed out)
May 22 11:00:46 seliius20664.seli.gic.ericsson.se mysqld[28769]: 2019-05-22 11:00:46 0 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs connect failed: Connection timed out
May 22 11:00:46 seliius20664.seli.gic.ericsson.se mysqld[28769]: 2019-05-22 11:00:46 0 [ERROR] WSREP: wsrep::connect(gcomm://seliius20663,seliius20664,seliius20662) failed: 7
May 22 11:00:46 seliius20664.seli.gic.ericsson.se mysqld[28769]: 2019-05-22 11:00:46 0 [ERROR] Aborting
[root@seliius20664 erriamp]# cd /var/lib/mysql/
[root@seliius20664 mysql]# clear

[root@seliius20664 mysql]# ls
aria_log.00000001  galera.cache  ib_buffer_pool  ib_logfile1  multi-master.info  mysql.sock          test
aria_log_control   grastate.dat  ib_logfile0     ibdata1      mysql              performance_schema
[root@seliius20664 mysql]#
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39997953

See sample MariaDB Cluster for usage which uses a custom MariaDB image and is a proof of concept for creating clusters

Comment: you should add this as comment